# android asynctask crash when trying to load an heavy page

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm programming an app with my brother, and today unfortunately,  I encountered with a problem.

When the app load a php page via my asynctask class it works fine. but I would like to program this situation: if the remote server is down, or crash, and doesnt display the right page, the application will show error message. but instead, the app crashes =[

I tried to load this page, for example: 
http://alonadoni.com/sql3.php
(I want to simulate that there is a problem with the server. the regular page is sql2.php and it works fine when the server works)

When the app try to load this page (sql3.php) , the app crashes.
I did another experiment : I created a file sql3.php, and wrote "aaaaaaaa" in the page, the app doesn't crash in this situation. it downloaded the data "aaaaa". in this case, the app show jsonexecption error.

Unfortunately, I can't get logcat because my old computer can't run emulators, and my phone also can't connect to my computer on developer mode =[ When I try application I create an apk then transfer the file to my phone and install.

my code is:

in OnCreate:

```
      String serverURL = sss() + "sql3.php?imei=" + imei; 
      new LongOperation().execute(serverURL);
```

outside OnCreate:

```
    private class LongOperation  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {





        private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        private String Error = null;

        protected void onPreExecute() {


        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                data[x] = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error2" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cancel(true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Error = e.getMessage();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error34" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                cancel(true);
            }


            return null;
        }

        public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {


            if (Error != null) {  
            } else {


        try {

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data[x]);
            name = json.getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"e" + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        }

             }
            x++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: do not use toast in do inbackground since ui is not be used in doinbackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DoInBackground** of **asynctask** needs to contain only **NON UI work** , hence referring to context and performing UI operations in UI thread may cause crash.
You can perform UI operations in postexecute of asynctask.

```
Hence Removing toast from above code which refers to UI operation will solve your issue
```